# Does Little Big Planet 2 give you any sort of in game perks or bennies for having a save from the first version?

Tags: little-big-planet-2, little-big-planet

Some sequels will reward fans for having played previous games. Is there anything like this in LBP2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Levels, materials, costumes... all will be in LBP2 if you have unlocked them in LBP1.

you will start with your LBP1 pod design, too

Comment: You also get a slightly different intro (*"Welcome back!  As you no-doubt remember.."*)

Comment: do you know if this is a one-time thing, or does it update each time? Say, if you haven't play LBP all that much - should you try and unlock as much as possible before getting LBP 2?

Comment: As far as I know, you can load the changes at any time.